# How can I add event listener to span added by DTColumnBuilder?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to add event onclick to a span added by DTColumnBuilder.

```
                DTColumnBuilder
                    .newColumn('Invoice')
                    .withTitle('<span class="li-table-header">Invoice</span>')
                    .withOption('visible', true)
                    .renderWith(function (data, type, full) {
                        return `<span style="color: #337AB7;cursor:pointer">Download</span>`;
                    }),
```

when I try too add onclick (<span onclick="test()" .../span>)
I am getting an error saying that test() is not defined even though I have defined test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code

```
<span ng-click="test()" .../span>
```

If test function is available in the current scope then use this.test() . according to the function scope do the function call

Answer (score 0):

you just use ng-click instead of onclick

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).